# Spreadsheets: how do I SUM values in a column, only if the text column has a 1?

Tags: excel, numbers, spread

Let's say I have this data

```
4     1
4     0
4     1
3     0
5     1
```

How do I write a function (using `SUM` or something like that) to add all the values on the left, if the values on the right are 1, or true

The total should be 13

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming columns A and B are used...

Check just for 1:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B5,"=1",A1:A5)
```

If you want to check for TRUE also:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B5,"=1",A1:A5) + SUMIF(B1:B5,"=TRUE",A1:A5)
```

Answer (score 0):

sort by column b, then auto-sum the values you want in column a.  cheap & lazy solution.